# File upload does not seem to work with `content-type: application/octet-stream`

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Having a problem posting a file upload to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=xxxx`
 - [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/file-attachment)

As far as I can tell, there are only one difference of importance between the documentation-provided curl request and our implementation's request - we're using "content-type": "application/octet-stream" instead of parsing the exact mimetype of the files we're sending.  If this could be the problem, I would love to know, as all we're getting back from FB is the generic "Sorry, something went wrong." html response.

The requests in question:

via cURL (successful) :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 463
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ce70fccbff4ca73d

--------------------------ce70fccbff4ca73d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipient"

{"id":"100016849000254"}
--------------------------ce70fccbff4ca73d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

{"attachment":{"type":"file", "payload":{}}}
--------------------------ce70fccbff4ca73d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test text file
--------------------------ce70fccbff4ca73d--
```

via our implementaion (fails):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------cbriejsxmxnhcdok
Content-Length: 642
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: hackney/1.8.6

-----------------------------cbriejsxmxnhcdok
content-length: 24
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-disposition: form-data; name="recipient"

{"id":"100016849000254"}
-----------------------------cbriejsxmxnhcdok
content-length: 43
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-disposition: form-data; name="message"

{"attachment":{"type":"file","payload":{}}}
-----------------------------cbriejsxmxnhcdok
content-length: 21
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="test.txt"

test text file
-----------------------------cbriejsxmxnhcdok--
```

We've tried matching all the headers exactly, including `Accept: */*` (which made exactly no difference) and `Expect: 100-continue` (which resulted in a failure to open write stream error).  Also, we attempted the same request in postman - it is working properly, and looks nearly identical to the curl request.

Edit: Just attempted to manually set the content-type in the `filedata` part to `text/plain`, which failed in the same way.

Edit 2: The successful raw curl request:

```
curl  \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"file", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F recipient='{"id":"<recipientId>"}' \
  -F filedata=@./test.txt \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<token>"
```

I can't really post our implementation code right now, as my position deals with a slightly abstracted interface above the underlying architecture and I just don't have the time to find the specific lines in question at the moment.  Also, it's written in erlang, which I don't fully understand.

Comment: Can you post the full successful curl request you're using and the code for your implementation?

Comment: You sure the Content-Length you are sending is correct? Your cURL request doesn’t send any, but the other one does - and if the value is not _correct_, I think that should pretty much mess up the whole thing. For your first two JSON values, the given Content-Length matches the length of the JSON data - but `test text file` would only be 14 bytes, not 21 (unless there’s “invisible” characters/whitespace that are not detectable here.)

Comment: I was using two slightly separate text files for testing, and the one through our implementation was rather salty, so I modified the text to be nicer and to match (hell of a catch!).  It can safely be assumed that the content-length is calculating correctly.